# Missing submodule 'homeKit' Error while building sample app on XCode6 on Mavericks

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, homekit

I've been trying to create a sample app using **HomeKit Framework**. while writing the code, everything seems fine. But while building it, IDE throughs ample number of errors and a warning "Missing subModule 'HomeKit' ".

I am using Xcode6 IDE on Mavericks.

**Highlight:** I tried to google it, found [a sample code on github](https://github.com/KhaosT/HomeKit-Demo/) & tried to build it on my IDE n guess what, same result for that too.

Any Idea?

Comment: Are you building to device? I have the same error, only when on device though.

Comment: No, for all am getting the same..

Comment: Did you add the `HomeKit` framework ? And dod you activate the HomeKit capability ?

Comment: @MarcelFalliere .. I did add the framework.. Not sure about activating capability. Whts that?

Comment: Go to your target app, then "Capabilities" tab. Scroll a bit and you'll see "HomeKit". Activate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the given sample code, its great demo app.
However, you must have "Paid Apple developer account".

After that the simplest way is, login with the apple developer account in Xcode.
(Xcode Menu->Preferances->Accounts)

Give full bundle identifier like com.myCompanyName.homekitApp
Now select project in Xcode, go to targets, In "General" tab select the "Team" it will display list of teams for accounts you have login to.

Now go to Capabilities enable Homekit, Xcode will automatically configure create application id, provisioning profile for given bundle identifier.

[image]

Varify all tick mark in Capabilities for Homekit.

Answer (score 0):

without a apple developer ID you can't use the HomeKit framework .
make sure that you added the capability